# In 8086 assembly, how to use stack in a child procedure?

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-16, integer-division

My task is to design a dword division child procedure (*divdw*) that will not overflow in 8086 assembly (I use masm5.0/masm.exe and masm5.0/link.exe and debug.exe in MS-DOS). `AX`, `CX`, and `DX` are used to save the result of *divdw*.  The following code cannot run yet.

Here is the task:

input:

> (ax)=low 16 bit of a dword dividend
>   (dx)=high 16 bit of a dword dividend
>   (cx)=16 bit divisor

output:

> (ax)=low 16 bit of the result
>   (dx)=high 16 bit of the result
>   (cx)=remainder

The formula I used to calc *divdw*:

> dividend/divisor = quot(high 16 bit of dividend / divisor) +
>   ( rem(high 16 bit of dividend / divisor) * 2^16 + low 16 bit of dividend ) / divisor

Here is my code:

```
assume cs:code

        code segment
start:  mov ax,4240h
        mov dx,000fh
        mov cx,0ah
        call divdw
        mov ax,4c00h
        int 21h

divdw:  push bx
        push dx                 ;ss:[0ch]

        mov ax,dx
        mov dx,0
        div cx
        mov ax,0                ;rem, only need dx
        mov bx,ss:[0ch]
        div bx

        ;; finish 1
        push dx
        push ax

        ;; get dx, into ax
        mov ax,ss:[0ch]
        div cx
        ;; finish 2
        push ax

        pop dx                  ;ax after 2
        pop ax                  ;ax after 1
        pop cx                  ;dx after 1

        ;; recover bx
        pop bx
        pop bx
        ret


        code ends
        end start
```

In this code, I am trying to use `pop` and `push` but did not define a stack segment.  Is this permitted? (In the debugger I found the `SS:SP` is given but the `push` cannot work correctly.)
If not, where should I define the stack and how to use it?

If I define a stack segment in the main procedure, it seems I need to save the `SS` and `SP` values in the beginning of the procedure, but where should I save them? Can I save them in the stack, or must I save them somewhere in memory?

The *start* main procedure is given for the purpose of testing.

Thanks!

---

**Edit**:

Thank you both! With your help, I finished this task. Code is now as follows:

```
assume cs:code,ss:stack

        stack segment
        dw 8 dup (0)
        stack ends

        code segment
start:
        mov ax,stack
        mov ss,ax
        mov sp,16

        mov ax,4240h
        mov dx,000fh
        mov cx,0ah
        call divdw
        mov ax,4c00h
        int 21h

divdw:  push bx
        push dx                 ;ss:[0ah]
        push ax                 ;ss:[08h]

        mov ax,dx               ;ax=0fh
        mov dx,0                ;dx=0
        div cx                  ;ax=1,dx=5
        push ax                 ;1, quot, should be dx when ret, as the high 16 bit of result
        ;; use dx=5 and 4240h to do div
        mov ax,ss:[08h]         ;ax=4240h.  rem, only need dx of last result, use low 16bit of dividend, ie. ax, as ax
        div cx                  ;ax=86a0h,dx=0h

        ;ax already is low 16bits of quot
        mov cx,dx               ;rem, store in cx
        pop dx                  ;1, high 16 bits of quot

        pop bx                  ;discard original ax
        pop bx                  ;discard original dx
        pop bx                  ;recover original bx
        ret


        code ends
        end start
```

---

**Edited on 20170724**

Yet another version, get rid of the ss:[08h], and used another 3 registers to store. I am not sure whether this is better, but it works.

```
assume cs:code,ss:stack

        stack segment
        db 16 dup (0)
        stack ends

        code segment
start:
        mov ax,stack
        mov ss,ax
        mov sp,16

        mov ax,4240h
        mov dx,000fh
        mov cx,0ah
        call divdw
        mov ax,4c00h
        int 21h

divdw:  push bp
        mov bp,sp
        push si
        push bx
        push dx
        push ax
        mov si,sp

        mov ax,dx               ;ax=0fh
        mov dx,0                ;dx=0
        div cx                  ;ax=1,dx=5
        push ax                 ;1, quot, should be dx when ret, as the high 16 bit of result
        ;; use dx=5 and 4240h to do div
        mov ax,ss:[si]          ;ax=4240h.  rem, only need dx of last result, use low 16bit of dividend, ie. ax, as ax
        div cx                  ;ax=86a0h,dx=0h

        ;ax already is low 16bits of quot
        mov cx,dx               ;rem, store in cx
        pop dx                  ;1, high 16 bits of quot

        pop bx                  ;discard original ax
        pop bx                  ;discard original dx
        pop bx                  ;recover original bx
        pop si
        mov sp,bp
        pop bp
        ret


        code ends
        end start
```

Comment: how is this loaded/linked? The stack should be prepared by loader

Comment: I use masm5.0/masm.exe and masm5.0/link.exe and debug.exe in MS-DOS .

Comment: A stack of only 16 bytes? You must be joking!

Comment: Please don't use `mov ax,ss:[08h]`. That's not good programming practise. Why don't you use the stack frame pointer `BP` like both answerers told you?

Comment: Sorry for that. I just not quite understand that for that moment. I will try out another version soon. Thanks @Fifoernik

Comment: About your edit on 24/7/2017. The whole idea of using a stack frame is _to address values that are on the stack through using the `BP` register_. Because the `AX` register that you want to retrieve is the __4th__ pushed (word sized) register below the line `mov bp, sp`, you can fetch it using `mov ax, [bp - 8]`. This also removes the need for a `SS:` segment override prefix or even the use of the extra `SI` register!

Comment: Ahh... Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to save them as long as the number of `PUSH` is equal to the number of `POP`.

That isn't always convenient, but it your case, it should be fine.

Except, you are popping the saved `DX` value into `BX` at the end, so that could be a problem.

EDIT:

I don't see that you need it in this case, but in general you can do this to restore `BP` and `SP`:

```
 push bp   ; first statement of subroutine
 mov bp, sp

 ...

 mov sp, bp
 pop bp
 ret
```

Within your subroutine, you then have `BP` to use as a base address for any parameters pushed onto the stack before the call. Again, your example doesn't show that, but you also don't seem to use the value you put in `AX` register and the statement

```
mov bx, ss:[0ch]
```

is a bit confusing. How do you know what is at that address?

Comment: FYI BP is the backup stack register. mov bp, sp

Comment: Yes, I only need to save bx; ax,cx,dx are used to save the result of divdw.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks for this. Should I use mov bp,sp in child or main procedure? If in the child procedure, should I backup bp first? My task is to design a divdw child procedure.

Answer (score 3):

> If not, where should I define the stack and how to use it?

How you define the stack segment depends on the assembler program. 
Sort of `segment stack` and/or `assume ss:stack`. There's no need to modify `SS:SP` directly on the startup, except `.com`/`model tiny` programs.

> it seems I need to save the ss and sp values in the beginning of the procedure, but where should I save them?

Typical program uses only single stack segment, so there's no need to save/modify `SS` register. Concerning `SP`, no, you obviously can't (shouldn't) save it onto the stack. The usual trick is:

```
push bp
mov bp, sp
... ; use [bp+4] to address the first argument on the stack
.... ; ss segment is assumed by default when [bp] used
mov sp, bp ; if sp was modified by some push/sub instructions
pop bp
ret
```

However it's only useful if you really need to work with the stack-based args inside of the procedure. Otherwise just use `push` / `pop` as needed.

Comment: Thank you @Matt . The `assume ss:stack` really helps. I will continue my study and see what `.com/model tiny` means.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake! I can't believe I wrote that silly replacement `SS:IP`.  Apologies.